# Error setting env thru subprocess.call to run a python script on a remote linux machine

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, env

I am running a python script on a windows machine to invoke another python script on a remote linux machine. I am using subprocess.call with ssh to do this, like below:
    `subprocess.call('ssh -i <identify file> username@hostname python <script_on_linux_machine>')` and this works fine.

However, if I want to set some environment variables, like below:
    `subprocess.call('ssh -i <identify file> username@hostname python <script_on_linux_machine>', env={key1:value1})` it fails. 
I get the following error:
    `ssh_connect: getnameinfo failed
    ssh: connect to host <hostname> port 22: Operation not permitted
    255`

I've tried splitting the ssh commands into list and passing. Didn't help. 
I've tried to run other 'local'(windows) commands thru `subprocess.call()` and tried setting the env. It works fine. 
I've tried to run other commands(such as `ls`) on the remote linux machine. Again, `subprocess.call()` works fine, as long as I don't try to set the environment.

What am I doing wrong? Would I be able to set the environment for a python script on a remote machine? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the environment on the remote side, you will need to do calls on the remote side. Try writing and uploading a wrapper script which does this env setting, e.g.

```
import subprocess
import sys


args = sys.argv[1:]
env = dict(zip(args[::2], args[1::2]))

subprocess.call(['python', 'script.py'], env=env)
```

Now you just have to pass this information in your original call, e.g.

```
subprocess.call('ssh -i <identify file> username@hostname '
                'python <script_on_linux_machine> %s %s' % (key, value))
```

Or some more extensible method of converting a dict to the required format.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the env variables I want to set will only be known at runtime - when I run the script on the windows machine. So, I will need to pass these environment variables to the script running on the remote machine at runtime as well.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that makes things clear. So, if I understand you correctly, I should now make two `subprocess.calls` - one for the setEnv.py and the other for the actual script that I want to execute. Will the `env` set in the first call be reflected for the second call? I can try and verify it, but I will need to wait till Monday. Hence, the question.

Comment: The idea is that the environment is passed through *command-line arguments* to the wrapper script, which then sets the environment for the real script.